# AWS Cloud practitioner: Does RDS require less administration work than Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

I am preparing my exam for AWS Cloud Practitioner and one of the resources I am using is the Test Bank that comes along with the book [AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner Study Guide: CLF-C01 Exam](https://www.amazon.de/Certified-Cloud-Practitioner-Study-Guide/dp/1119490707/ref=asc_df_1119490707/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=380211180934&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=15547257361499602778&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=2276&hvtargid=pla-774475927562&psc=1&th=1&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=76466509846&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=380211180934&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=15547257361499602778&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=2276&hvtargid=pla-774475927562) and there is question I think it is wrong in the Test Bank.

I tried to contact [Wiley Efficient Learning](https://www.efficientlearning.com/), the provider who offers and maintain the Test Bank, but their customer service is really bad (side note: the book is fairly good, the training provider is awful).

Maybe someone can help me here.

The question is:

```
Which of the following AWS services would require the customer (i.e., you) to assume the least responsibility for administration? (Select TWO).

A. Elastic Beanstalk
B. Elastic Compute Cloud
C. Relational Database Service
D. Route 53
```

According to the Test Bank, the right answers are A (Elastic Beanstalk) and C (Relational Database Service).

However I think that the right answers are A (Elastic Beanstalk) and D (Route 53).

**Why?**

Well, with RDS you have to pick up the right SQL engine, instance type, memory, vCPU, IOPS,... You have to setup a maintenance window, backup retention, deciding on the level of reliability you want enabling/disables multi AZ, enabling resources to access through security groups and, when it is running, you have to monitor it and right-size it if you under- or over-provisioned (for example, if you have enough connection slots to support your workload) plus monitor for potential malicious access.

Also, if the engine you selected is reaching the EOF, you are responsible to update it.

On top of that, you have the administration of the databases you create, but that is using the service, not administrating the service.

**On the contrary**, with Route 53 you can either register a domain name or you manage the resolution of domain names. But that is using the service, not administrating it.

With Route 53 you don't have to care about reliability nor capacity nor elasticity nor auto-scaling nor backups... AWS will provide the domain name registration and domain name resolution for you.

You have to configure your hosted zones, but that is using the service not administrating it.

What do you think?

Comment: AWS cert questions are better asked at https://old.reddit.com/r/AWSCertifications/.

Comment: The A and C are correct. If you apply your R53 reasoning to Elastic Beanstalk it also fails.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question and perhaps the language could be clearer.

My answer would be A & C having the `least responsibility for administration`. My reasoning would be:

A - You only have to configure the service. Yes there are a lot of options available to configure, but you never have to deal with security patches on the underlying instances, closing ports on your ALB, etc

B - You have access to the machine itself which, apart from the Security Group, is effectively an open IP on the public internet and you must perform all security and maintenance yourself.

C - Same as A; only a huge amount of configuration, the "deep" parts are still hidden away

D - There's less configuration options in general so it might appear "easier", however those options are very fundamental to how it operates. You have access to the SOA records, DNS publishing, etc. There aren't really any "hidden" aspects to R53